# How do I clone an AngularJS node while also cloning the event bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive where I want to clone the element that the directive applies to.  In one particular use of the directive, the element has a button with a click handler bound to it.  I want my cloned element to also have this click handler.  However, the conventional methods I know for cloning nodes aren't working for me.  An example of what I've tried so far follows.  Keep in mind this example is simplified for demonstration and the ultimate purpose of my directive is not just to clone the element.

```
module.exports = function($window, $injector){
    return {

       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           // Neither of the following methods actually copy the click handler over to the clone.
           var myFirstClone = element[0].cloneNode(true); 
           var mySecondClone = angular.element(container).clone(true)[0];  
           element[0].after(myFirstCone);  // doesn't have the click handler
       }
    }
}
```

Is there another method that I should be using?  Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it well, you wants to clone your directive ?

Comment: I'd like to clone the element that the directive applies to.  The directive is attribute applied.

Comment: Your problem here is that Angular will not parse your cloned element. Cloning something in an handler is not the AngularJS way of doing so

Comment: Ok so what would be the AngularJS way of cloning my element?

Comment: If you're just appending the same element after itself, why don't you use `<my-element ng-repeat="n in [0,1]"></my-element>`?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that.  Ultimately the purpose of my directive is to pin something to the top of the screen when it's scrolled out of view.  The reason I'm using a clone instead of just adding a class to the element to give it a fixed position is to avoid the sudden jerkiness that occurs from the vacuum left by the element that was previously in the page flow.  If instead I create a clone with a fixed position right as the original element scrolls out of view then the transition is completely smooth -- but the events on it no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cloning the element, you should use ng-if or ng-show in your top level controller. Have a property that checks if you are scrolled past a certain point. When the property evaluates to true, the element will show up. Also, you can use css to make transitions smoother (e.g. ease in/out), I wouldn't rely on javascript for visuals behaviors like that.